# how to use substr in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I have the following extract of a code used in SAS and wanted to write it in SQL Server to extract data.

```
substr(zipname,1,4) in("2000","9000","3000","1000");run;
```

How do I write this in SQL Server ?

I tried and got this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected

Comment: How about translating what this means? What should it do exactly with the `IN` clause?

Comment: After fixing the double quotes, you can use `left(zipname, 4)` instead of `substring()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sql server, there's no `substr` function (it's [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx))

by the way, you need a complete query...

```
select blabla
from blibli
where substring(zipname, 1, 4) in ('2000', '9000', 3000', '1000')
```

assuming zipname is a varchar or something like that...

Comment: I definitely will name my temporary tables `blibli` with `blabla` columns from now on.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! Why didnt I think of substring? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a table that you are getting the records from, and zipname would be a column in the table. The statement would be something like this:

```
select * from tablename where substring(zipname,1,4) in ('2000','9000','3000','1000')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the first x characters, you can also use the left() function.

```
 where left(zipname,  4) in (values go here)
```

Bear in mind that your values have to be single quoted.  Your question has double quotes.

Comment: Isn't it `left(zipname,4)`?